Ubuntu Core installation asks for localhost admin and password
Ubuntu Core 24 on 127.0.0.1 (tty1)  
localhost login:   
Password:  

Whatever I put here, it doesn't accept it. The main issue is, it worked on my first try with empty image, adding just the adguard home snap and core 22. it passed this phase, installed and let me configure wlan and ssh user, worked like a charm, but now I can't get pass this no matter what I try.
I tried:

multiple reflashing,

creating new ssh using its name and passkey

using my Ubuntu One account's username and passkey

any combination of those 2.


Nothing works, I don't know what to do and I don't know why it passed the first time and now it's getting stuck.
btw I have added this into my model. I just have a model JSON that I sign and ubuntu-image my-model.model .
"defaults": {
        "system": {
            "user": {
                "name": "parallels",
                "ssh-keys": ["ssh-rsa AAAA....

That's all I do. I then flash the image onto a USB and run it on a jasper-lake.

Are you trying to login from a local physical keyboard/monitor? That doesn't look like an ssh connection.

The prompt is not the same as when it asked to create a user. I dont know if its about the sso or not, but yes Im trying to input the required credentials with a keyboard on the local machine. As I mentioned, it magically passed this phase on my first installation and later asked for ssh user. and I dont think its about waiting some time because i left it for an hour and nothing changed.

After the initial prompt to create the user and configure the network, Ubuntu Core is intended to be accessed via ssh. There is no local login password, and no easy way to create one. If you need local login, or cannot use ssh, then Ubuntu Core might not be the best choice.

Thanks, but I'm not trying to locally login, I'm just trying to pass this phase and configure the device, but don't know how :(.
